# Framing environment that works like \fbox

Tags: environments, framed

I need to create an environment that works like `\fbox`. I checked out [`framed`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package, but it does not have such thing. So far my workaround is:

```tex
\newenvironment{frame}
  {\begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline}
  {\\\hline\end{tabular}}
```

Is there a better solution?

This is to typeset centered framed boxes of hard-wrapped text, like in [Algorithms](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/) book by Jeff Erickson. My solution with `tabular` is based on his source.

I am looking for something simple. I do not feel like loading a big package just to get an environment that does what `\fbox` does plus lots of bells and whistles.

Comment: There are many options, depending on what you want to frame and how much you want to customize the frame - `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` seem the most obvious candidates. Maybe you can explain a bit more what your use case is?

Comment: Another important question for which you need to specify the need is whether or not page breaking is required.  Of course, `\fbox` would not allow it---on the other hand, many environments are structured to allow page breaks.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, the behaviour of `\fbox` is fine for me, i think i would rather avoid page breaks.

Comment: Have you considered `\framebox`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, how could i make an environment out of `\framebox`?

Comment: No, that's just a command that will wrap its argument in a frame, so it's not what you want, I guess.

Comment: You could use `\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myenv}[1][3in]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\BODY}}}`, to create a  parbox environment with an `\fbox` around it, but of course it loads a package. Optional argument specifies the parbox width.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, this is what i was looking for, you may post this as an answer. It uses a package, but it looks like a LaTeX patch. Too bad `\newenvironment` does not do something like this by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I use `environ` to create something you can `\fbox`, in particular, a parbox of default 3" width.  As it is set up, it would be placed inline, unless you set it off with `\\` or `\par`.  Thus, it will also in those cases lay to the left.  All those things can be altered in the definition if you want to `\centerline` the `\fbox` for example, or set it automatically on a line of its own, between the pre and post text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myenv}[1][3in]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\BODY}}}
\begin{document}
Pre-environment\\[5pt]
\begin{myenv}[2in]
xyz\\
pdq
\end{myenv}\\[5pt]
Post environment
\end{document}
```

[image]